# Youtube Data Api android

Tags: android, listview, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to display my **Youtube** channel videos in list view with `Youtube Data Api` using `thumbnail` view in android app and play video `onClick`. How can it be done? I just found to load a single Youtube video, have to put video ID. So how it can be done for loading my whole channel videos?

Like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably use [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to fetch all the videos from your channel then display them using a [Recycler View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szUc84dko38).